# Create your own custom signals in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, signals

I would like to define my own custom named signal apart from SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 (or any other standard signals).
How do I go about this?

Comment: It's really hard, it's basically impossible.  There are already 32 signals, and it looks like they have to correspond to the individual bits in a 32-bit `int`.  When I added one, I had to usurp an existing one.  But where I started adding it was in `arch/arm/include/asm/signal.h` (because I was working on ARM; it might be `arch/x86/...` for you).  Then from inside the kernel I called `internal_kill()` to send my signal out to user processes.

Comment: I tried to redefine one of the signals with a custom name but it does not recognize the signal when I call it from a user app. Even I'm working on ARM.

Comment: For one thing, the header file that defines the signal names within the kernel source directory may be different from the header file that ordinary user-mode C files see when they're being compiled.  You may have to keep those two separate instances of the header file in sync manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html states that you can define `real time signals` - they have no predefined meaning.

```
   The range of supported real-time signals
   is defined by the macros SIGRTMIN and SIGRTMAX.  POSIX.1-2001
   requires that an implementation support at least _POSIX_RTSIG_MAX (8)
   real-time signals.

   The Linux kernel supports a range of 33 different real-time signals,
   numbered 32 to 64.  However, the glibc POSIX threads implementation
   internally uses two (for NPTL) or three (for LinuxThreads) real-time
   signals (see pthreads(7)), and adjusts the value of SIGRTMIN suitably
   (to 34 or 35).  Because the range of available real-time signals
   varies according to the glibc threading implementation (and this
   variation can occur at run time according to the available kernel and
   glibc), and indeed the range of real-time signals varies across UNIX
   systems, programs should never refer to real-time signals using hard-
   coded numbers, but instead should always refer to real-time signals
   using the notation SIGRTMIN+n, and include suitable (run-time) checks
   that SIGRTMIN+n does not exceed SIGRTMAX.
```

There's hardly anything to add: use `SIGRTMIN+n` when `SIGRTMIN+n < SIGRTMAX`. Make a compile time check for that (i.e if you need more signals than your implementation of `libc` allows, you're in trouble).

e.g. have something like `#define SIGRUBBERDUCK (SIGRTMIN+3)`